# Can we use the link of an HTML file to render it with flask?

Tags: html, flask

In my Flask App instead of serving html from the templates folder, can I use a link to the html file in return `render_template("url of html file"`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Instead, get the html file contents via a http(s) get, e.g. [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and then pass the contents to Flask's [`render_template_string`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=render_template#flask.render_template_string) .